# Python: UI alternative to tkinter askdirectory

Tags: python, file, directory, user-input

I am currently using this tkinter code so the user can select a directory for files to be output to, which works perfectly fine:

```
    usi.sfl = tkFileDialog.askdirectory() + '/'
```

But it looks like this:
[No normal human locates files like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Indzg.png)

Other alternatives I've found include this: [Better, but the lack of favorites on the left is concerning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xEUtB.png)

What I'm hoping for is something like this:
[The dream](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E16ER.png)

I've done a lot of searching, but I haven't found anything that covers what I want. I'm assuming it must be out there, but I just cannot seem to find it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using tkinter askdirectory to do the same and it works perfectly.

Maybe changing the code would help?

```
from tkinter import filedialog as fd
directory=fd.askdirectory()
```

Now the directory is a variable and can be used to both read/ write files.

For writing to a file in this directory, you can specify the filename by adding the filenname string to directory using `os.path.join()`

```
import os
fileout = os.path.join(directory + '/<filename>.<ext>')
```

Comment: The code works just fine, the problem is the resulting UI. The code you provided gives me the exact same results as in: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Indzg.png I'm unsure how that code would change the UI as it's just calling the function in a different way.

Comment: I had a hunch it might not fix it. tkinter just uses the windows settings to display. Is it possible that your windows is set for high performance settings which lowers the graphics?

Comment: It is possible to select a directory without using this UI, and is default in many other programs. I am just unsure how to access it. Graphics settings would not in any way impact UI in this manner.

Comment: Does it give the same issue if you use filename = fd.askopenfilename()  option? 
I still think there is a system component involved here.

Comment: You can specify the directory manually directory = "C:/Test" 

There should be other options in GUI - will search.

Comment: That displays something closer to the 2nd image and also does not return a file directory, only a file. To clarify, are you saying that when you run askdirectory() your file selection looks like this? https://i.stack.imgur.com/E16ER.png

Comment: That's exactly what I'm saying - I use windows7 & it gives me all the options you see in the default file selection window.

These are the other GUI available:
https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/othergui.html

Comment: My users have also reported this UI (in both windows 7 and 8), which is why I'm certain it's not an issue specific to my computer. I've looked through a few of those already, and they all seem to have the same problem when it comes to choosing a directory specifically (not files). I'm looking for a way around the terrible windows default.

Comment: One way to ascertain if it's windows related is to try some of the other options such as PyQt and see if the issue persists.